# How can I map a character to a pointer of another type?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a `char*`. I want to parse it, character by character, and store the location of each in an `int*`.

With the dummy-string "abbcdc", the content should be as follows

```
char       int*
-------------
'a'     -> 0
'b'     -> 1,2
'c'     -> 3,5
'd'     -> 4
```

I want this to be accessible through a `char*` containing the entire alphabet, so that each character in the alphabet-pointer points to each separate integer-pointer. This is where I'm lost.

I know I can point to a pointer using the double-asterisk syntax

```
int **a = &aLocations;
```

But I don't really know how to refer to the locations-pointer by using a character as a reference. I am pretty new to C, so all pointers (pun intended) are appreciated.

**Update 1:**

```
int *aLocations = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
aLocations[0] = 13;
aLocations[1] = 9;
aLocations[2] = 57;

int **a = &aLocations;
```

This seems to work as expected, but `a` obviously remains an integer, not a char. I was thinking of writing a function something along the lines of

```
int *getCharLocations(char c) {
  // returns a pointer to the stored character locations
}
```

but I don't know how to proceed with implementing it.

Comment: Note that an `int*` points to an `int`. `1,2` are two integers. You can arrange for the `int` to point to `1`, but how do you know how many more numbers follow 1?

Comment: The dynamic reallocation and storage of each respective size is indeed something I have to take into consideration, but for now I am content with finding out how to map a character against an integer pointer!

Comment: so you want to have array containing alphabet (a-z) from which you could go to array of indices of particular character ?

Comment: @krystah You should show what you've managed to write, so far. Just dropping a specification for a rather specific problem like this and expecting full solutions isn't always a good approach, here.

Comment: I don't really know how to proceed, that's why I haven't written much. Updating with what little I have now.

Comment: That's not really a question which is appropriate on this site. You may want to learn a simpler language first. E.g. in C++ you'd just use a `std::map<char, std::vector<int>>` so you could do `mymap['a'].push_back(1);`. In C, that takes about 300 lines of code.

Comment: If you have a `int[26][MAX] index_array;` and want to access the 5th array for storing indexes of the accurence of the character `char c = 'f';` then you could use the ascci values to calculate that index: `index_array[c - 'a'][next] = i;` (c - 'a' == 5). same goes for upper case letters.

Comment: @A4L: Except that you'd either have to keep track of `next` for each character, or determine it each time.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I should have wrote `...[next[c - 'a']]` ... not beeing able to have the actual size of an array makes this simple task a pain in C.

Comment: Well guys, maybe you could comment on my answer here, i wonder what would you say, since i think i solved it and there wasn't much pain involved. Thanks in advance

Comment: @4rlekin I'm glad to hear you didn't suffer

Comment: @lelloman i guess it makes you a good person then

Comment: Note that your first sentence is extremely confusing: "I have a char*. I want to parse it, character by character, and store the location of each in an int*". A `char*` is a pointer to char, and not necessarily a string or even an array of char. Same for `int*`: it is a pointer to int, not necessarily an array of ints

Comment: how to convert from an integer to a character?  really easy.  First the integer must be positive, then the integer must be in the range (using the ascii character set) of 0...255 then (char)intvalue does the job.  If you want to limit that to only the alphabetic characters, then the value of the integer is even more limited to two ranges 1) 'a'...'z' and 'A'...'Z'  (you can treat the individual char as an integer by int value = 'a'; (that will be 65), etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok then.
Although it would be possible it would be pretty ugly and complicated.
So if you do not mind i would suggest to drop `char` and use integers exclusively.
It is possible since `char` is in fact just small integer.

So first you would need to create your two dimensional alphabet array:

```
int *alphabet[26]; // this will create 26 element array of integer pointers
```

Now we will fill it:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    alphabet[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(int)); //alloc memory for 100 integers (should be enough for human language if we're talking about single words here)
    alphabet[i][0] = 'a' + i; // this will put a letter as first element of the array
    alphabet[i][1] = 2 // here we will keep index of first available position in our indices array
}
```

So now we have array like this:

```
'a', 2, ...    // '...' means here that we have space to fill here
'b', 2, ...
...
'z', 2, ...
```

And you can add indices of occurences of letter to such construction like this:

```
alphabet[index_of_letter][alphanet[index_of_letter][1]] = index_of_letter; //put index at the end of array
alphabet[index_of_letter][1]++; // increment our index of available position
```

---

That's pretty much it.
I didn't test it so it may need some polishing but such approach should do the trick.
PS.
Someone in comments above noted uppercase letters - in such case you would need to extend array to 52 characters to store also occurences of uppercase letters (also fill first element with uppercase letter in for loop for such records). But i guess you will manage from now on